# construction of bst from preorder traversal

Tags: binary-search-tree, tree-traversal, insertion, preorder, construction

While constructing Binary search tree from given Preorder traversal, can't we use normal method for construction of BST from set of array values instead of following the method given [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/construct-bst-from-given-preorder-traversa/). If not ,please give counter example where my approach fails. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can! When constructing your BST from the preorder traversal, all that matters for the algorithm is that the values themselves exist and are accessible. A set of array values should work perfectly!